How to create a reference cell button act like select a range in pivot table in VSTO Excel Add in?
I want to create a feature allow user reference a cell in excel workbook and highline active cell like pivot table in excel in this image:

I already change background of cell but seem it can't change background of active cell.
Hope you can get my question. Thanks.

I already find the way to do this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60664715/13316722
